# Python dataclass type hints and input type conversions

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, casting, python-dataclasses

How should we type hint for dataclasses which can accept multiple input types but cast them all to a particular type during, e.g. `__post_init__`. Example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Collection, List

@dataclass
class Foo1:
    input_list: Collection 

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.input_list = list(self.input_list)

@dataclass
class Foo2:
    input_list: List

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.input_list = list(self.input_list)
```

For class `Foo1` we will get type warnings if we try something like `foo1.input_list.append(0)` because the type checker doesn't know that `foo1.input_list` is a `List` (it only knows it is a `Collection`). On the other hand, class `Foo2` will give type warning for `foo2 = Foo2((1, 2))` because it expects a `List` input, not a `Tuple`.

What is the appropriate way to write a dataclass (or any class) that does mild type conversion on its attributes during `__post_init__`?

Comment: Just don't use the dataclass code generator. It is a convenience for defining a common pattern if your use case doesn't fit that pattern, it is probably better just not to use it

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Could you please provide an answer following the approach you describe? Would you type hint `Collection` in the `__init__` signature but type hint `List` in the `__init__` body when you define `self.input_list`?

Comment: Well, I prefer attribute type hints in the class body, not `__init__` body, but that's my preference. But this approach is already in an answer below

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Just to be clear (your phrasing could be read multiple ways) they can still use `dataclass`, they'd just define `__init__` manually (suppressing auto-generation of that specific method) while still benefiting from the auto-generation of `__repr__` and `__eq__` (and others depending on arguments passed to the `dataclass` decorator), neither of which has any issues with the mixed typing (by the time either of them get involved, only the type annotation on the instance attribute matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this does not appear to be a case where `dataclasses` will do the heavy-lifting for you. If you want the annotations to differ between the `__init__` arguments and the attributes themselves, at present, you need to write the `__init__` by hand. For a class like this one, it's pretty trivial:

```
from collections.abc import Collection

@dataclass
class Foo:
    input_list: list[int]

    def __init__(self, input_list: Collection[int]) -> None:
        self.input_list = list(input_list)


foo = Foo((1, 2))
foo.input_list.append(0)  # No objections raised by mypy, even in --strict mode
```

Obviously not ideal if the `dataclass` is more complicated, but it does work (`mypy` raises no complaints if you do `foo = Foo((1, 2))`, `foo.input_list.append(0)`).

Comment: Ok, so the type hint (annotation?) in the `__init__` signature obviously kicks in during `Foo(1, 2)`. I guess the type hint for `input_list` as the class attribute is what kicks in during `foo.input_list.append(0)`?

Comment: @Jagerber48: Yeah, `def __init__(self, input_list: Collection[int]) -> None:` says "I accept anything that is a collection of `int`s", the `input_list: list[int]` at top level says "The `self.input_list` attribute will always be a `list` of `int`". Since `Collection[int]` is explicitly converted to `list` (and such a conversion is something all `Collection`s will support, since they're all iterable by definition) before the assignment, the assignment is legal, and from then on, the attribute is always `list[int]` specifically and supports all `list` features.

Comment: @Jagerber48: To be clear, `input_list: list[int]` is not annotating a class attribute; it's annotating what the instance attribute will be (no actual class attribute is created as a result of that annotation). You need assignment to create a class attribute (which does get weird with `dataclasses.field` which assigns to a class attribute that `dataclass` consumes to define instance attribute-related stuff), and [`typing.ClassVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ClassVar) to explicitly annotate as a true class attribute.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481550/10466809 for a thorough discussion of the pros and cons of putting the type hint in the class body or `__init__` body.

Answer (score 0):

Use Union:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List, Union, Tuple

@dataclass
class Foo:
    input_list: Union[List, Tuple] = field(init=True)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.input_list: List = list(self.input_list)


foo1 = Foo([1, 2])
foo1.input_list.append(0)

foo2 = Foo((1, 2))
foo2.input_list.append(0)
```

Comment: That fixes nothing; you'll still get `mypy` errors of the form: "error: Item "Tuple[Any, ...]" of "Union[List[Any], Tuple[Any, ...]]" has no attribute "append"  [union-attr]". When an attribute is annotated as a union, any operations on it are expected to be supported by *all* of the types in the union.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree with your point about `Union` not helping. But Amir194 had done something else, which is type hinting `self.input_list` in the body of `__post_init__`. This isn't described in the body of the answer, but I think this makes the type checking during `append` work without error.. at least it works for me in pycharm.

Comment: @Jagerber48: Like I said, it definitely doesn't work for `mypy` checking (even without `--strict`); I copy-pasted the exact code from this answer directly into a local source file and ran `mypy` against it and saw the error from my comments (with both `mypy` 1.0.1 which is what I had installed, and `mypy` 1.2.0 which I updated to, to be sure it wasn't changed in newer versions). PyCharm may be more permissive, but `mypy` is the usual standard for typechecking. It complained on a second issue (no type annotation on `__post_init__`), but adding `-> None` only fixed that complaint, no others.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see. I don't have easy access to `mypy` checking, but it's something I'm interested in. My previous comment is actually not quite correct. Pycharm gives no warnings even if there is no `List` type hint in the `__post_init__` method as long as `List` appears in the `Union` for the `dataclass` field definition. This honestly sounds incorrect to me, since as you say, `append` should appear for ALL types in the union if it is to be a valid operation on the attribute. If `List` does not appear in the `Union` then the warning can be cleared by the `List` hint in `__post_init__`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I've made an answer similar to this one with more explication about my specific setup. Would you mind commenting there to confirm that my answer fails `mypy` checking? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75989534/10466809

Comment: @Jagerber48: Yep, aside from objecting to the lack of any type annotations on `__post_init__` itself (`note: By default the bodies of untyped functions are not checked, consider using --check-untyped-defs  [annotation-unchecked]`), it errors on line 14 and 17 (the lines which call `append`) with `error: "Collection[Any]" has no attribute "append"  [attr-defined]`. Adding the `-> None` it requests dismisses the note, but does not change the other errors. If you run with `--strict`, it also objects to the untyped contents of `List` and `Collection` (which implicitly default to `Any`).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is heavily inspired by the answer from @Amir194. The solution is to type hint that `self.input_list` is a `Collection` in the `dataclass` initialization, but a `List`, in `__post_init__`. I get no warning in Pycharm (which is what I'm using for code inspection) when I use the code below. However, @ShadowRanger points out that this approach DOES give warnings through `mypy` which is, I think, a more standard checker. That said, "spiritually" this code looks right to me, so I'll probably go forward with it. It says that `input_list` can be a `Collection` at input time, but that after `__post_init__` it has been converted to a `List`.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Collection


@dataclass
class Foo:
    input_list: Collection

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.input_list: List = list(self.input_list)


foo1 = Foo([1, 2])
foo1.input_list.append(0)

foo2 = Foo((1, 2))
foo2.input_list.append(0)
```

Comment: I mean, you could just ignore Pycharm if you are going to do this

Comment: And it isn't "spiritually" correct at all, it is *wrong*. A `Collection` does not have an `.append` method. It is just as wrong as the Union approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess the reason I said it's "spiritually" correct (there's a fair chance my statement is just wrong) is that I think of `__post_init__` as redefining the type of `self.input_list` from whatever it was before (`Collection`) to `List`. So if this re-declaration has indeed happened, then it makes sense. But apparently different type checkers disagree as to whether the hint in `__post_init__` counts as a re-declaration of the type.

Comment: I think you just need to understand that PyCharm's type checker is woefully inadequate. Type checkers that follow PEP 484 (and subsequent PEPs) *all find this wrong*. So mypy, pyright etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that makes sense. Thank you for the clarity. I'll leave this answer up because I think the answer and comments have interesting specifics for Pycharm users.